# Mass update individual records in Rails (PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have stumble on a problem to update a set of records.

In Database I have

```
id | name   | info::hstore | friends[]::varchar 
1  | Claire | {}           | []
2  | Mary   | {}           | []
3  | Bob    | {}           | []
```

I have for an example an array of hashes:

```
[ 
  {id: 1, name: "Claire", info: {age: 21, sex: 'f'}, friends: ['Mary', 'Bob']}, 
  {id: 2, name: "Mary", info: {age: 16, sex: 'f'}, friends: ['Mike']},
  {id: 3, name: "Bob", info: {age: 28, sex: 'm'}, friends: ['James']}
]
```

All records are already in DB, I want only to UPDATE the existent with columns from hashes, the hashes all have same number of fields to update: name, info and friends.

There is a gem active-record-import but it does only inserts. Also the method #update_all does not work as I have individual data to update each record depending on id.
Don't want to make a raw SQL insert as my rows have Postgres hstore and array types, don't want to make lot of data manipulations.

There could be about 10,000 - 100,000 records to update.

Env: Postgres 9.4, Rails 3 (also if there is a good solution in Rails4 would appreciate to hear about)

Comment: Please give a more specific example of what you want to update and how the data is stored in the hash. You have `{id: 2, name: "Claire"}`, does that need to update the record :name to 'Claire' for record where id: = 2? Or is it only the ones with more data than just the name that need updating? Are these all in the same table?

Comment: Thanks, I have updated a question

Comment: Have you tried any sort of iterator?

Comment: Which iterator? I am currently just getting all objects as User.where(id: ids_form_list) and update one by one

Comment: Can you post what code you have? Even if you don't like the code or don't want to use it, people need to see it to know what you don't want to do.

Comment: Also, do all of the hashes have the same fields? i.e. they all have :info and :friends? Are there any that would have more than just those two? It makes it easier if every hash has the same structure.

Comment: Which columns do you want to update? `id` seems to be the PK, so this one is to identify the row. All other columns, incl. name? What if the row does not exist? Insert it instead? So it's an UPSERT, really? If there are no other columns, you could just `DELETE` all matching rows and `INSERT`.

Answer (score -3):

So I am not sure if you are against this method from what you've said so far but you could do:

```
update_info = [{id: 1, name: "Claire", info: {age: 21, sex: 'f'}, friends: ['Mary', 'Bob']}, 
               {id: 2, name: "Mary", info: {age: 16, sex: 'f'}, friends: ['Mike']},
               {id: 3, name: "Bob", info: {age: 28, sex: 'm'}, friends: ['James']}
                   ]

update_info.each do |row|
  user = User.find(row[:id])
  user.update(info: row[:info], friends: row[:friends])
end
```

that is about the only way to get your info from an array of hashes into the DB. With Postgres you can do a mass update from another table with something that is similar to a join. But if you are going to go to all that trouble, then you should just do this on the DB console `psql` or with a GUI DB program that lets you do SQL queries. Some things are just better done in the DB because that is what it's designed to do.

Comment: You could use ruby to generate a .sql file that you could just run against the DB on the command line, but I don't know the Postgres syntax for hstore, so you'd have to write that yourself. Is all of this getting into your Rails app from a text file?